# Call Recognize.im API using Fetch instead of Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to call Recognize.im's API using Fetch. Recognize.im provides the code to make a call using Node.js which I can't use for this project.
https://github.com/RecognizeIm/node.js-client/blob/master/RecognizeAPI.js

What I currently have is giving me the following error:

> Fetch Error :-S TypeError: Network request failed(…)

Here's my code, I removed my API keys for this post, and the data that's being passed is a base64 image string.

```
var MD5 = require("crypto-js/md5");

recognize(data) {

  var CLIENT_ID = '';
  var API_KEY = '';
  var CLAPI_KEY = '';

  var hash = MD5( API_KEY , data );

  fetch('http://clapi.itraff.pl/v2/recognize/single/'+CLIENT_ID, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'x-itraff-hash': hash
    })
  })
  .then(
    function(response) {

    console.log(response)

  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);

  });;


}
```

Comment: This might be either a CORS problem, or a problem with the parameters that you provide. Either way, your structure as such looks fine.

Comment: My hope was someone could take a look at the way they're doing it via Node (which I'm not familiar with) and figure out what's wrong with the parameters I'm passing.